# Monero stratum on yiimp pool

Tags: mining-pools, algorithm

Is there a way to add Monero XMR to YIIMP mining pool.
The `randomx.conf` at `/var/stratum/config` is below.

```
[TCP]
server = testpool.online
port = 8888
password = {password}

[SQL]
host = localhost
database = yiimpfrontend
username = stratum
password = {password}

[STRATUM]
algo = randomx
difficulty = 512
max_ttf = 40000
reconnect = 1
```

Can I add Monero XMR to YIIMP pool this way?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve build the stratum supporting RandomX and replaced with yiimp stratum.
It works. https://github.com/tpfuemp/yiimp-randomx

Comment: The yiimp stratum linked is actually an early fork of mine, which was intended for Luxcoin's RandomX fork. Unsure why jtgrassie would take the time to correct grammar/capitalization.. but not mentioning his own (admittedly very good) Monero stratum?
An attempt at humor perhaps?

Comment: How do I replace the default stratum with that one?

Comment: Hi, I've struggled a lot with YIMP then moved to miningcore ```https://github.com/coinfoundry/miningcore```